# Move Threejs mesh to the center of another mesh

Tags: three.js, mesh

I have the following structure in my scene (imported from glb):

[image]

I try to move the mesh svgGroupsvg_test to the center of mesh named M_Top (red cross is the expected location).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function engraveSVG(object, value) {
    //object is the name of the target mesh
    var svgMeshName = 'svgGroup' + value
    loadSVGandFit(svgMeshName, object, value).then(res => {

        var svgMesh = scene.getObjectByName(svgMeshName);              
        svgMesh.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 1)

        const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 20 );
        svgMesh.parent.add(axesHelper)

        moveCenterMeshToOtherMeshCenter(svgMesh, scene.getObjectByName(object))
    })
}
```

I tried the following functions:

```
function moveCenterMeshToOtherMeshCenter(centerMesh, otherMesh) {
    // get the center positions of both meshes in the local world
    const centerMeshPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    const otherMeshPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    centerMesh.getWorldPosition(centerMeshPosition);
    otherMesh.getWorldPosition(otherMeshPosition);

    // calculate the difference between the center positions of both meshes
    const difference = otherMeshPosition.sub(centerMeshPosition);

    // translate the center mesh by the difference
    centerMesh.translateX(difference.x);
    centerMesh.translateY(difference.y);
    centerMesh.translateZ(difference.z);
}

function moveCenterToOther(centerMesh, otherMesh) {
    const centerBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(centerMesh);
    const otherBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(otherMesh);

    const centerPosition = centerBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
    const otherPosition = otherBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

    const offset = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(otherPosition, centerPosition);
    centerMesh.position.add(offset);
}
```

Is there something wrong ? Get center return a value around 0.

I chose to add the svg mesh in the same group of my target mesh. But it changes nothing.

The axes is also in the local coordinate.

Any help would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I add my SVG in the root of the scene. I am now able to get the correct bounding box size and center in the world coordinates.